# Why is AudioNode.disconnect(Audio Param) disconnecting from more than the specificied audio param?

Tags: javascript, audio, disconnect

In the MDN for [AudioNode.disconnect(destination)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode/disconnect) it states that

> If this value [destination] is an AudioParam, then the connection to that AudioParam is terminated...

but when I call the function it not only disconnects from the specified AudioParam, but also the AudioNode.  Similarly, when disconnecting from the node it also disconnects from the AudioParam.

Below is a snippet in which, if you click a connection button and then click either of the remove buttons, it will remove whatever connections you've created, rather than just the one specified.

Further, there is no `InvalidAccessError` thrown as the docs say it should, if something is wrong.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug here?

```js
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var osc1 = audioCtx.createOscillator();
osc1.type = 'triangle';
osc1.frequency.value = 300;
osc1.start();

var osc2 = audioCtx.createOscillator();
osc2.type = 'sine';
osc2.frequency.value = 600;
osc2.start();


var gain = audioCtx.createGain();
gain.gain.value = 0.5;

gain.connect(audioCtx.destination);
osc1.connect(gain);




function disconnectOsc2() {
  osc2.disconnect(gain);
}

function disconnectOsc2AM() {
  osc2.disconnect(gain.gain);
}

function connectOsc2() {
  osc2.connect(gain);
}

function connectOsc2AM() {
  osc2.connect(gain.gain);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="disconnectOsc2()">Disconnect Osc 2</button>
<button onclick="disconnectOsc2AM()">Disconnect Osc 2 AM</button>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="connectOsc2()">Connect Osc 2</button>
<button onclick="connectOsc2AM()">Connect Osc 2 AM</button>
```